# AngularJS custom tag directive how to expand {{scopevar}} when coming from $http calls

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

### Attention

This question has been rephrased and answered here:

- [AngularJS: model data from http call not available in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338219)

---

I'm experimenting w/ AngularsJS directive. Created a simple  directive but the {{scopevars}} are not present when coming from an $http call. E.g.:

Controllers

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Card) {
    $scope.abc = "this works well";
    $scope.user = User.get({userId: 1}, function(user) {
      });
}
```

User service (works well)

```
angular.module('userServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/user/:userId.json', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                userId: 'user'
            },
            isArray: true
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the directive code (broken):

```
/**
 * Create the <pretty-tag>{{var}}</pretty-tag>
 */
.directive('prettyTag', function($interpolate) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var text = element.text();
        var e = $interpolate(text)(scope);
        var htmlText = "<b>" + e + "</b>";
        element.html(htmlText);
    }
};
```

Results:

```
// => In HTML view <pretty-tag>{{abc}}</pretty-tag> => <b>this works well</b>.
// => In HTML view <h1>{{user.name}}</h1> => <h1>Bob</h1>.
// => In HTML view <pretty-tag>{{user.name}}</pretty-tag> => Doesn't work (empty).
```

Can someone help me understand why `<pretty-tag>{{user.name}}</pretty-tag>` which is a var set via an $http call is not working?

Comment: What values assign to "var" variable or can you provide controller code or create a jsfiddle for the same..

Comment: Also can you check you have missed the brackets in code you have provided in current post

Answer (score 1):

Below the working jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/cPVDn/10/

```
.directive('prettyTag', function($interpolate) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var text = element.text();
        var e = $interpolate(text)(scope);
        // =============> problem e is always empty
        console.log(e)

        var htmlText = "<b>" + e + "</b>";
        element.html(htmlText);
    }
};
});
```

Comment: I updated my question. My code (and yours) work for most case but not when the var is set from an http call. See update question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to assign the user value in the `callback` of the `.get()` method like this

```
User.get({userId: 1}, function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
});
```

And you can pass the model `user` to the directive like this

```
<pretty-tag ng-model='user'></pretty-tag>
```

And inside the directive, access the text model via `ngModel` from attributes.

```
var text = attrs.ngModel;
```

Comment: The scope is already updated in my code. I also tried yours but it does not work.

Comment: @supercobra What does User.get() do? Can you paste the code? It is very important you paste the code for some key operations so we will have a more clear idea about the problem. Now everyone is guessing.

Comment: @supercobra Updated. Please try.

Comment: Still same behavior. The data coming from the async call is not present in the directive... I wonder what to do next to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

In the `link:` function, try:

```
  $scope.$watch('user', function () {
    var text = element.text();
    var e = $interpolate(text)(scope);
    var htmlText = "<b>" + e + "</b>";
    element.html(htmlText);
  });
```

This is untested, but it looks like the page renders before the $http call returns data, so $scope.user is undefined.