# AngularJS: model data from http call not available in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

There seems to be a bug where model data fetched from an http call is present in the $scope but not in a directive. Here is the code that illustrates the problem:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/supercobra/hrgpc/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).directive('prettyTag', function($interpolate) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var text = element.text();
        //var text = attrs.ngModel;   
        var e = $interpolate(text)(scope);
        var htmlText = "<b>" + e + "</b>";
        element.html(htmlText);
    }
};
});

function MyCtrl($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
$scope.method = 'JSONP';
$scope.url = 'http://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero';

$scope.fetch = function () {
    $scope.code = null;
    $scope.response = null;

    $http({
        method: $scope.method,
        url: $scope.url,
        cache: $templateCache
    }).
    success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = status;
    });
};

}
```

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h1>Angular $http call / directive bug</h1>
<p>This fiddle illustrates a bug that shows that model w/ data fetched via an http call
is not present within a directive.</p>
<hr>
<h2>HTTP call settings</h2>
<li>Method: {{method}}
    <li>URL: {{url}}
        <br>
        <button ng-click="fetch()">fetch</button>
        <hr/>
         <h3>HTTP call result</h3>

        <li>HTTP response status: {{status}}</li>
        <li>HTTP response data: {{data}}</li>
            <hr/>
            <h2>Pretty tag</h2>
            <pretty-tag>make this pretty</pretty-tag>

            <hr/>
            <h3 style="color: red" >Should show http response data within pretty tag</h3>
            [<pretty-tag>{{data}}</pretty-tag>] // <=== this is empty

</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/supercobra/hrgpc/

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the content of the directive in your directive implementation. Since the $http request is async, the directive completes before the data is retrieve and assigned to the scope.

Put a watch on `data` variable inside the directive and then re-render the content, something  like

```
 scope.$watch(attrs.source,function(value) {
                var e = $interpolate(text)(scope);
                var htmlText = "<b>" + e + "</b>";
                element.html(htmlText);
            });
```

Based on @Marks feedback and your request i have update fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/V6sDs/1/

Comment: So at least that works. Thanks. This also makes the directive locked to watch the $scope.data variable. Any way not to do that?

Comment: @supercobra, `<pretty-tag attr1="data">{{data}}</pretty-tag>`, then watch that attribute: `scope.$watch(attrs.attr1, function(value) { ... })`

Comment: This tells me all directives should have a built-in watch mechanism because their data could come from http calls...

Comment: As long as you keep the reference to data object, and clear and fill it instead of replacing the reference, this watch would work.